# Showing result in Android layout

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm totally new to this and am trying to figure out how to actually show the result of this little function in the layout of android. Have been searching and searching and I can't figure out exactly what it requires.

```
package com.example.proyectoparteb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        readUsage();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private float readUsage() {
        try {
            RandomAccessFile reader = new RandomAccessFile("/proc/stat", "r");
            String load = reader.readLine();

            String[] toks = load.split(" ");

            long idle1 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
            long cpu1 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
                  + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(360);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

            reader.seek(0);
            load = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();

            toks = load.split(" ");

            long idle2 = Long.parseLong(toks[5]);
            long cpu2 = Long.parseLong(toks[2]) + Long.parseLong(toks[3]) + Long.parseLong(toks[4])
                + Long.parseLong(toks[6]) + Long.parseLong(toks[7]) + Long.parseLong(toks[8]);

            return (float)(cpu2 - cpu1) / ((cpu2 + idle2) - (cpu1 + idle1));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    } 

}
```

Comment: What do you want to display this "result" as? A textview?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Show the CPU usage in a textview.

Comment: Selecting a best answer will give incentive for people to give answers to your future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, kind of a vague question but here is an example of something you could do.

Add a TextView to your layout in your main_activity.xml or whatever you have named it.

Set the id as @+id/myTextView.

In your code, import the TextView widget with:

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Then initialize it in your method:

```
TextView cpu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

and set the text to something:

```
cpu.setText(readUsage().toString());
```

There you go. As with any language make sure you play around with stuff to learn it. You can use the eclipse graphical editor to add widgets and change properties like text size and colour etc.